# How can I get user location and check if it's located in a specific area on map?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I'm developing this app and using the react native map, i already know how to get the user location from the device gps, but my question will be **is there is any way to check if the user located in a specific area like a country or a city**.

**Example:** The user located in the USA and my specific area is France because my app is only for French people, how to check if that user is not located in France so that i could alert him a message saying you are out of France this app not for you.

Answer (score 0):

i think you've got tow major solutions here on with

```
  const mylocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
  const geocode = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(mylocation.coords);
  # reteceive the country code from the location API
  geocode[0].isoCountryCode,
```

or get the polygon boundaries for France (.geojson file) and check i your lat lng is inside of it.

Comment: ok but what if it's the same country but i want a specific city from all the other cities of that country, is there is a way to do that ?

Comment: oh yes sure if you want to narrow down to city there are also 3 choices there: zip and city or regions name like so: `zip: geocode[0].postalCode` or `city: geocode[0].city` or `state: geocode[0].region`

Comment: do i need to install a library for this to work, because none of this is working for me :/

Comment: can you share some of your code to expose your problem ?

Comment: ```const mylocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
const geocode = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(mylocation.coords);
cosole.log(geocode[0].city);```

Comment: can you share your actual implementation?